# unable to remove interfaces from bridge, automatically reatached after restarting network

Tags: centos, networking, bridge

I'm working on Centos 7.2 kernel version 3.10.0-327.36.3.
I'm writing a simple bash script that modifies some network parameters of a server.

I'm trying to remove some interfaces from a linux bridge, but they keep coming back after restarting the network service.

the initial configuration is:

```
4: enp7s0f2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br-MCP state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 00:10:f3:5e:fe:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp7s0f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br-MCP state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 00:10:f3:5e:fe:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

first I delete the "BRIDGE=br-MCP" line from ifcfg-enp7s0f2 and from ifcfg-enp7s0f3.
then I remove the interfaces using brctl tool:

```
brctl delif br-MCP enp7s0f2 
brctl delif br-MCP enp7s0f3
```

so far everything works as expected.
at the end of my script I restart the network service in order to apply other changes I made to other interfaces.
after restarting the network service, the interfaces are reattached to the br-MCP bridge.

I tried going through the process manually, same result, after restarting the network service the interfaces reattached to the bridge.

network manager is disabled.
the system has an openVswitch running, but it has nothing to do with those 2 interfaces.

what am I missing here?
how can I remove the interfaces from the bridge permanently?

best regards,
Igal

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: there is no such directory..